# Importing data from Excel to database using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import

I want to import data from Excel to database using asp.net. I'm using VS-2012 to do this.

This is my code for the click event. But when I upload the file and click on the button the page shows "Page not found" error.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
            OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet$]", OleDbcon);
            OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            OleDbcon.Open();
            DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string con_str = "Gems1ConnectionString1";

            SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con_str);
            bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "tbl_energy_report";
            bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
            Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"))), File.Delete);
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            Label1.Text = "Succefully Imported the File";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            Label1.Text = "Please Select A File";
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

on the first line try to assign the full path manually without using fileupload and with local path like:

```
string path = @"C:\fileName.xls";
```

and see if it works!